# take screenshot in chrome device emulator mode

Tags: google-chrome, width, device, viewport

I am using a laptop computer with a max resolution on 1366px.
I want to take a screenshot of how a website look in the device emulator mode in chrome - when I set the width to be bigger - like 1600px.

When I do this - the device viewport becomes overflows out of my chrome window and a part of it is hidden  - how do i take a screenshot of this -
print screen wont work. Is there a plugin or a chrome extension??

Answer (score 41):

found this menu, which take screenshot of device screen only
[image: screenshot device simulation in chrome developer devtool]

latest chrome have "Capture full size screenshot" 
[image]

Comment: No '+' or thanks. Fine. But as a comment to your answer, why haven't anyone '+'-ed it yet? It is THE answer to the question.

Comment: @andersoyvind If I try this using a resolution larger than my physical screen size, the screenshot is black for the part falling off the physical screen. Or, if the zoom is set smaller than 100% so it fits on the physical screen, the screenshot is downscaled as well. So unfortunately the solution does not work (I'd expect it to work though, it would make a lot of sense)

Answer (score 15):

in latest chrome we can capture node ,

1. open developer tool
2. select node to be capture
3. press CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P, it will open a "command menu"
4. filter commands using "screenshot" keyword
5. choose "capture node screenshot"

[image]

more info at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes